# return inside a switch block yields "unreachable code" warning

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm writing UnityScript code and at one point in my program, I want to terminate a function from within a `switch` block. This is a boiled down version of my code:

```
function Move(target: int) {
    var targetTransform : Transform;
    switch (target) {
    case 0:
        // do something including assigning targetTransform
        break;

    case 1:
        // do something including actually moving my object
        return; // since I moved already, I want the function to terminate here

    default:
        // do something including assigning targetTransform
    }
    object.Move(targetTransform); // object is locally available
}
```

Now for whatever reason, the Compiler gives me a

```
Assets/Scripts/GameMaster.js(490,9): BCW0015: WARNING: Unreachable code detected.
```

The line is the one containing the `switch`.

From my previous research, I found many similar problems, but all of them had actually unreachable code, like for example `break` statements after the `return`s or a `return` at the end even though each and every `case` `return`ed at some point. This is not the case here, I just want one of my `case`s to return out of the function altogether, while the others shall `break` out of the `switch` and go on from there.

**Is there a way to get rid of this warning? What is causing it in the first place, is this just a bug?**
If at all possible, I'd prefer not to use a `boolean` and check for it after the `switch` block... This just seems like overkill only to terminate one `case` early.

Comment: I tried adding breaks to your switch statement, even tried ensuring there's no `#pragma strict` at the start of my test file, but the warning still comes up. Does seem silly, but a boolean check is probably the way to go. I've come across this myself; is annoying but not a biggie.

Comment: This indeed seems like a Unity bug. I didn't work with UnityScript myself, but on C# it's not hard to encounter compiler crashes due to outdated Mono version. Have you tried contacting Unity about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug exists at least since [2010](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/13045-WARNING!-Unreachable-code-detected!?p=412212&viewfull=1#post412212). Although it's perfectly legal to use a `return` statement instead of a `break`, the compiler will complain about unreachable code.

You have basically two options

1. ignore the warning and keep your code nice and clean
2. work around the warning by replacing the `return` with a `boolean` + `break` and check for the `boolean` after the `switch` block

As far as I know you can't even [disable](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/55253/javascript-switch-returns-warn-for-unreachable-cod.html) or [suppress](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/39993-Suppressing-warnings) the warning. It's possible in C# but UnityScript seems to lack this feature. So this would result in a third possible solution: convert your code to C# :-)